# how to delete folder with angular.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

how to delete folder with angular.js?

I tried this [angular-filesystem](https://github.com/maciel310/angular-filesystem/blob/master/src/filesystem.js)

---

I set up that plugin in my app. everything is ok but when I press delete button, I'm getting this error: `Object {text: "Error getting directory", obj: FileError}`
this is my path directory:

`var path = 'http://localhost:3001/uploads/audios/';`

Comment: how to define path correctly? what is correct path?

Answer (score 0):

When you define your module, write the deletefolder method in $scope as below

```
$scope.deleteFolder = function(path, recursive) {
    fileSystem.deleteFolder(path, recursive).then(function() {
        $scope.messages.push(path + " deleted");
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        $window.alert(err.text);
    });
};
```

and call it in any event of a element as below

```
ng-click='deleteFolder("documents/", true)'
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Object {text: "Error getting directory", obj: FileError}` and how to define correct path? this is my path: `var path = 'http://localhost:3001/uploads/audios/';`

Comment: ng-click='deleteFolder("uploads/audios/", true)'

Comment: Thangaperumal :/ it doesn't work. still error: `Object {text: "Error getting directory", obj: FileError}` what can I do? I'm using Mean Stack and is this plugin works for mean?

Comment: hey wait, I try to make folder. I made folder with that plugin and it works, then delete and it works but it makes virtual folder and it deletes virtual folder :( I want to do this in local system. can you help me and tell how to delete local folder?